# Am i use "AngularJS directives to integrate Google Maps " or Normal angularjs to build a GPS based tracking web application.?

Tags: java, angularjs, google-maps, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new in **AngularJS** and Google Map.

As per my project i have to build a GPS based tracking system where i can show latest position of a device ,Playback ,and current position location with lat & long.In UI part i am using AngularJS and back end is Spring MVC with Hibernate.

My question is that am i use AngularJS directice to integrate google map or write normal code in angular AngularJS and connect it to google map.which one will be better for this environment?

Anybody please refer me some link or some source to build my project,

I written a normal code to create position in google map using **lat& lng**.

**I Written this code  :**

```
   var myangu = angular.module('mapsApp', []).controller(
    'MapCtrl',
    function($scope, $http) {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 4,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(22.5726, 88.3639),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };

        $http.get("/java/position").then(
                function(positionlist) {

                    alert(JSON.stringify(positionlist)); 
                    $scope.polist = positionlist.data;
                    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.polist));
                    alert(JSON.stringify(positionlist.speed));
                    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document
                            .getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


                    var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({
                        lat : positionlist.latitude,
                        lng : positionlist.longitude
                    });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position : mylatlng,
                        map : $scope.map,
                        title : 'address'

                    });


                });

    });
```

But first alert showing correct but second alert result is "`undefine`" .Cannot read "`positionlist.latitude`".

How to solve this ?

Now how to set  marker on Google Map based on database value(**lat&long**).

**Alert message is:**

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time": 1475152462000,
      "valid": true,
      "latitude": 22.474121666666665,
      "longitude": 88.39709333333333,
      "altitude": 0,
      "speed": 0.539957,
      "course": 257,
      "power": null,
      "address": "kol",
      "other": "<info><protocol>gt06</protocol><satellites>3</satellites><index>4</index></info>"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "time": 1475152472000,
      "valid": true,
      "latitude": 22.47413166666667,
      "longitude": 88.39704,
      "altitude": 0,
      "speed": 0.539957,
      "course": 273,
      "power": null,
      "address": "ban",
      "other": "<info><protocol>gt06</protocol><satellites>3</satellites><index>5</index></info>"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "time": 1475152482000,
      "valid": true,
      "latitude": 22.474191666666666,
      "longitude": 88.39689,
      "altitude": 0,
      "speed": 1.619871,
      "course": 281,
      "power": null,
      "address": null,
      "other": "<info><protocol>gt06</protocol><satellites>3</satellites><index>6</index></info>"
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "url": "/java/position",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the marker on the map:

```
// define the position
var myLatLng = {lat: data.latitude, lng: data.longitude};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: $scope.map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=de